# How to set relative thread priorities for the threads in my application, without requiring root access

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, scheduling

I've got a threaded C++ application that runs under Linux, Windows, and MacOS/X (using pthreads under Linux and MacOS/X, and `_beginthreadex()` under Windows).

In the application, I spawn three threads:  A, B, and C.  I'd like to make it so that thread A's performance won't/can't be affected by the CPU usage of thread B, and so that thread B's performance, in turn, won't/can't be affected by the CPU usage of thread C.

The obvious solution to this is to set thread priorities, with A getting the highest thread priority and C getting the lowest.

The fly in the ointment, however, is that this application will usually be running without any special privileges, and most of the set-thread-priority APIs I've come across require root privilege in order to work.

Is there any way for a non-root process to accomplish this?  (Note that I'm not looking to get priority over threads in other processes, just to set the relative priority between the threads in my own process)

Comment: `setpriority()` on Linux does not need root to increase the niceness (lower the priority) of a thread, only to *lower* the niceness.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to make the effects to the thread via CPU-load independent from each other would be to run them on different cores ( if this is possible of course ).

So you need to check which CPU-Cores are available ( using Linux and MacOS/X look here how to get this: [cpuset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html) ) and if there are Cores available use the pthread_setaffinity_np-call ( you can find him  [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) ).

If this is not possible you can change the priority. As mentioned before you will not need to be root to do this as far as I know.

There are similar calls on Windows available.

Comment: The shortcoming of this approach is that it only works on machines that have at least three cores.

Comment: Right, when having less than 3 cores you need to change the priority.